# Where can I add sum calculation in Cloudsim

Tags: java, netbeans, cloudsim

I'm new in cloudsim.

I would like to know is there any possibility to **(as an example send two numbers to cloudsim, make cloudsim do the sum calculation function, and send back the result to the client?)**

I have to do something similar but I don't know where can I add the sum calculation in cloudsim?

Answer (score 0):

CloudSim is a Cloud simulator, which means that Cloudsim simulate a hole IaaS Cloud environment. It cannot do any claculation, but simulate a CPU workload executed by VMs and host machines. 
Here is a good intoduction to Cloudsim: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2EF4ZcyoXg&list=PLGe95EHDPn-X5Opz5xB-3rUnqr_PXOOnv